# Tate Conjecture birational invariant?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, motives, algebraic-cycles

Is the Tate Conjecture stable under birational equivalence?
In particular, is the Tate Conjecture for rational varieties known?

Comment: Take an arbitrary smooth projective $X$, embed it in $\mathbf{P}^N$ (with codimension $>1$), and consider $Z = {\rm Bl}_X \mathbf{P}^N$. Then by the formulas for cohomology and Chow ring of a blowup, I think the Tate conjecture for $X$ and $Z$ should be equivalent statements.

Comment: Correct (the comment). In particular it is enough to check the Tate Conjecture for rational varieties. A similar argument works for the Hodge conjecture